# Rails: Instance of IO needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, io

I have this error in my Rails app:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (instance of IO needed):
    30:       <tr>
    31:         <% @product.images.each do |img| %>
    32:           <td id="product_image_<%= img.id.to_s %>">
    33:             <%= image_tag img.miniature %><br />
    34:             <%= link_to_remote raw(t(:delete)), :url => { :action => :de
lete_image, :id => img.id }, :update => "product_image_#{img.id.to_s}" %>
    35:           </td>
    36:         <% end %>
  app/models/image.rb:45:in `formats_from_yaml'
```

img.miniature looks like this:

```
  Images::formats.each_key do |name|
    define_method(name) do
      self.formats_from_yaml[name][:url]
    end
  end
```

Images::formats is a hash table of format names as a string, width and height in pixels and a quality for the image-jpg.

What's the mistake?

And formats_from_yaml like this:

```
  def formats_from_yaml
    YAML.load(self.formats)
  end
```

self.formats is a hash with the name of the format and the url of the image. edit: self.formats is the hash as yaml.

What confuses me is that if I call Image.first.formats_from_yaml by the rails console, it will work.

What's the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

`YAML.load` [takes an IO stream or string as a parameter](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/YAML.html#M002015) and loads the document from it. If `self.formats` is a Hash, why pass it to YAML.load? It seems like the block should be:

```
define_method(name) do
  self.formats[name][:url]
end
```

Comment: Can you call `Image.first.miniature` in the console? That may give a hint. On a hunch I would add logging to `formats_from_yaml` just before the `YAML.load` call to ensure that `self.formats` is what you expect it to be in that context and try loading your page again. (`Rails.logger.info self.formats.inspect`)

Comment: Image.first.miniature from console works, it returns the url of the image beginning from the root

Comment: Interesting. I still strongly suspect that `self.formats` is nil for some reason when the site tries to call that method (that's the error YAML.load will throw)

Comment: do you have any other idea? this still didn't helped

Comment: Did you try adding the console logging to the method (as described in my first comment) and seeing the output during actual page load? Some tracing (or a debugger) in and around that method should help narrow down what's going on.